# How to reload session attribute on page refresh in JSP?

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

I am setting data in session attribute after fetching from DB once user is logged in. But when user reloads the page, I want the session attribute to be updated with the latest data from DB so that *updated* data is displayed on the screen using

```
<c:forEach items= "${sessionScope.allPosts}" var="post">
... 
</c:forEach>.
```

It is basically just 2 lines of code in Servlet where `PostsDao.getPosts()` will fetch the latest data:

```
List<Post> allPostsList = PostsDao.getPosts("ALL", userId);
session.setAttribute("allPosts", allPostsList);
```

How do I make this call every time when user click on page refresh?

Comment: i was just going to post answer already typed but this question got closed :(

Comment: you can post in the comment! :-)

Comment: You can write a `function` when page gets reloaded everytime you can call this function which will redirect you to the `servlet` where your code has written and again use `request.getRequestDispatcher("Yourjsppage")..` to come back to same jsp page .

Comment: okay. So if I am using `getRequestDispatcher`, then will this process without going to the other page? Like I don't want to be redirected and the come back.

Comment: use `window.location = "YourServletUrl";//redirect to servlet`  and then come back to same page using `request.getRequestDispatcher("Yourjsppage")..` your code should be in `doGet()` method of servlet.Also the link provided as duplicate is also helpful refer that as well

Comment: Okay will try this. Thanks a lot @Swati!!